# How to apply styles to neighboring elements in a list

Tags: html, css

Can I accomplish this scenario using only CSS?

I have an unordered list of elements of arbitrary length that lay out into a grid of four elements across

```
**** **** **** ****
*  * *  * *  * *  *
**** **** **** ****

**** **** ****
*  * *  * *  *
**** **** ****
```

When a user mouses over an element, then some additional content will dropdown below the element and push the rows below it down.

```
**** **** ---- ****
*  * *  * |^ | *  *
**** **** ---- ****
-------------------
| Content is here |
-------------------
**** **** ****
*  * *  * *  *
**** **** ****
```

The main thing is that the dropdown needs to fill up the parent container width-wise. I've done this using `position: absolute` and having the `<ul>` element be `position: relative`.

I was thinking that maybe something with an `nth-child` might work to essentially set the bottom margin for the neighbors and push the lower elements down, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

I'm trying to avoid resorting to doing this in Javascript if possible.

### Edit

Here's a fiddle of what I've got so far: http://jsfiddle.net/pYw34/

Comment: Do you have any existing HTML/CSS I can test something out with?

Comment: sounds cool.  You should be able to just ad a margin to the bottom of the list item to give you the gap (depending on how you did your grid), but then it's a matter of positioning it.  Definitely agree with Josh that it would be nice to have the markup and CSS.

Comment: Can you fix the height of the dropdown panel? Also, are you using floats or inline elements or table-cells?

Comment: @MarcAudet - I *think* I can fix the height of the dropdown panel. The content will be arbitrary, but it shouldn't be significantly long.

Comment: @JosephMarikle - It seems to mess with the flow though where only the list items directly below will get pushed down. That's why I'm wondering if I can use some sort of selector to get the elements in the row and set the margin-bottom on them

Comment: This is a tough one.  Your mark-up makes sense semantically, but to push down a row of floats, you need your drop down panel to be inserted in the document flow between two rows of floats.  You almost need to order your content differently: 4 images panels then 4 content panels then 4 more images then 4 more contents... in fact, you would need to wrap each 4-image/4-content assembly in a wrapper (like a row).

Comment: @MarcAudet - Yeah, I'm starting to lean more toward just restructuring the HTML to allow for this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want.

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/pYw34/1/)

Not an easy rule, however:

```
.about__list__item:nth-child(4n):hover:after,
.about__list__item:hover + .about__list__item:nth-child(4n):after,
.about__list__item:hover + .about__list__item + .about__list__item:nth-child(4n):after,
.about__list__item:hover + .about__list__item + .about__list__item + .about__list__item:nth-child(4n):after
{
    content: '';
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I made the element yellow to track it, of course that element should be invisible.

Comment: Nice. That selector is a little gnarly, but definitely workable.

Comment: Very impressive, a good use of selectors, an example worth examining closely.  Well done!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have much trouble just so long as the item display is just for show (i.e., I doubt it can be clickable) and can be placed as a child of the element triggering the event.

- [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bzwPQ/2/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul class='mylist1'>
        <li id='item1'>
            item1
            <div class='dynamic-content' style='background:blue;'>
                Some content.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id='item2'>
            item2
            <div class='dynamic-content' style='background:green;'>
                Some content.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id='item3'>
            item3
            <div class='dynamic-content' style='background:red;'>
                Some content.
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id='item4'>
            item4
            <div class='dynamic-content' style='background:orange;'>
                Some content.
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>



    <ul class='mylist2'>
        <li>
            item1
        </li>
        <li>
            item2
        </li>
        <li>
            item3
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {width:500px;padding:5px;}
.mylist1{margin:0px 0px 5px 0px;}
.mylist1 li, .mylist2 li {display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;padding:3px;border:solid 1px black;}
.dynamic-content {display:none;left:55px; margin-top:10px;position:absolute;padding:5px;border:solid 2px grey;color:#dedede;font-weight:bold;}
#item1:hover > div.dynamic-content {display:block;}
#item1:hover {margin-bottom:40px;}
#item2:hover > div.dynamic-content {display:block;}
#item2:hover {margin-bottom:40px;}
#item3:hover > div.dynamic-content {display:block;}
#item3:hover {margin-bottom:40px;}
#item4:hover > div.dynamic-content {display:block;}
#item4:hover {margin-bottom:40px;}
```

Comment: The main thing with this is that the elements are all in one list. They aren't separated into two separate lists

Comment: Given the limitation of how the list is built, this really a JavaScript/jQuery problem.

Comment: @MarcAudet I very much agree.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is by nature not a functional solution - there's no good reason to avoid javascript for this implementation.

I'd implement by separating my elements into rows like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
        <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

See the full implementation:
http://jsfiddle.net/n6Yz6/7/

It's a little weird on some edge cases but you should be able to get the idea from it.