# adding an element in between a row of floated elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-float

I have a bunch of boxes that are aligned in a grid.

They are all floated to the left, and then margin and width of one box is about 33%, so that once three boxes are next to each other, the next boxes are going in the next row. fairly even thirds.

**This is what i start with:**
[image: Start]

when clicking on a box i now would like to add a box under the box i clicked on.

i want to see it happening in a manner where pretty much just the space between the row of boxes is increased, and the new box is squeezed into that space.

**This is what i would like to see:**
[image: desired goal]

currently i simply use jquery's `.after()` to add a box after the box i clicked on. this box has `clear:both;` and it will work perfectly, but ONLY when clicking on the third box... when i click on the second or first box, the following boxes of the same row are floated into the next row. *of course that's totally predictable, because it does exactly what i told it to do.* **but i want them to stay there! i just dont know how.**

**This is what i get instead:**
[image: the problem]

**what would be the best way to accomplish this?**

Here is an example of my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/z3ggf/1/

Comment: Mind if we get some more code so that we can see what you've done?

Comment: Well, it's doing exactly what you are telling it to do. Clearing the boxes after the div you clicked, throwing the others to the next line. Would be good to see some code, as mentioned by Xander.

Comment: here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/z3ggf/1/

Comment: A similar problem was posted earlier at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768842/how-to-apply-styles-to-neighboring-elements-in-a-list The solution is directly applicable to this problem and worth a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically, you need to find the last (third) box in the row then append some html

```
$(".box").click(function(){
    var next_third_box_index = Math.floor($(this).index('.box') / 3) * 3 + 2;            
    var $third = $('#container .box:eq('+next_third_box_index+')');      
    $third.after('<div class="break"></div>');                   
});
```

**jQuery demo:**

- http://jsfiddle.net/9MMWs/

**Docs:**

- http://api.jquery.com/index/

---

This is how you find the index of the thrid box in the row where div has been clicked:

```
Math.floor($(this).index('.box') / 3) * 3 + 2;
```

- if you click box 0, third box index equals floor(0 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 2
- if you click box 1, third box index equals floor(1 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 2
- if you click box 2, third box index equals floor(2 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 2
- if you click box 3, third box index equals floor(3 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 5
- if you click box 4, third box index equals floor(4 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 5
- if you click box 5, third box index equals floor(5 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 5
- if you click box 6, third box index equals floor(6 / 3) * 3 + 2 = 8
- ...

Comment: Good idea! I was hoping there might be an option with the position attribute or something like that... for some reason would prefer to actually put the newly inserted element directly after the clicked element in the code...

Comment: seems more logical - the element added is like a settings panel that appears underneath the element clicked on. So it seems as if it would be best to keep them together.

Comment: maybe it is logical for human being, but not for html/css browser/parser :)

Comment: oh I didnt catch your thing was a link... so really i want to put the code after the element i clicked on and display it under the element i clicked on. i omitted the ramifications of displaying it exactly under the element for this question, as i thought the problem extracted is just the spacing in between.

Comment: Okay I give in... :D This seems to be the only possible solution to this. It's not quite as nice as I'd like it to be, but I guess it does what it's supposed to do. Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute." http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-7.html